# Magento 1.7 - Admin create new order, "custom price" tick box missing

Tags: magento-1.7

I hope someone can help me cause I'm just confused at the moment. Up until yesterday when I wanted to create an order manually in the admin backend, I would add products and they would have the "custom price" tick box for each item so you can manually change the price if you wanted. I need this feature sometimes and suddenly since today that tick box is just gone. I cannot change the price anymore of any product that I manually add to an order. Even when I edit it afterwards I still can't change the item price.

So what happened between yesterday and today...
I uploaded an extension which I didn't end up liking and removed all the files which was uploaded. I was careful not to remove anything else which wasn't part of the extension. But for some strange reason the whole website crashed. Couldn't get into frontend or the backend. Had to contact hosting provider for the to do restore to a backup which was made this morning luckily. Now all is fine again and website is back. I also updated all my product prices today via MAGMI importer and that went smooth. I then went and manually cleared all the cancelled orders/invoices/credit memos/shipments in the database so they wouldnt show up in die admin backend or the frontend when customer logs in. Only kept completed/processing/pending orders in the database.

So, I have no idea what could have caused that "custom price" tick box to just vanish. Any help on how to get it back will be greatly appreciated.

Some info:
Magento v1.7.0.0.
All products = simple

Please help.

Thank you
Coenraad

Answer (score 0):

Eventually tracked down the culprit causing the error. Well, an area which was causing it. To pinpoint the exact problem is bit difficult.

I seems that it was a combination between MAGMI importer and some column values that caused the custom price box to disappear. The values in question has no real affect on the display of the products on the website. Its more admin orientated values for the backend it seems. Just as a added measure I disabled the reindexing plugin for MAGMI and manually doing it in magento after import.

All is working now :)